# how to select database in this way - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-division

i have this table

```
id   owner   group     model  
1    1       shapes    circle  
2    1       shapes    rectangle  
3    1       shapes    squire  
4    2       fruits    apple  
5    2       fruits    orange  
6    2       fruits    banana  
7    3       shapes    circle  
8    3       shapes    rectangle  
9    3       shapes    star
```

which each owner select a group and enter 3 choice, now i want to find the owner who select shapes and entered circle and star.

it must return owner id = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `group` and `model` are unique for every `owner`

```
SELECT  a.owner
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   a.[group] = 'shapes' AND
        a.model IN ('circle','star')
GROUP   BY a.owner
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ff1c/1)

otherwise, you need to uniquely count the number of `model`

```
SELECT  a.owner
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   a.[group] = 'shapes' AND
        a.model IN ('circle','star')
GROUP   BY a.owner
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT a.model) = 2
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i think it is mysql, i work with ms sql 2008. can you convert it?

Comment: here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce2f6/2 but you need to escape the column name `group` with bracket because it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: thank you new sqlfiddlle is working,thank you let me check and understand yore solution, let ask if i have any problem, thanks again.

Comment: is there any tutorial to describe your method? i search 1 week in web, but i didn't this use of group by, that's great.

Comment: you problem is somewhat called `Relational Division` see here [SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 0):

Within the specified parameters this will work:
    SELECT owner WHERE [group] = 'shapes' AND model = 'circle'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT owner WHERE [group] = 'shapes' AND model = 'star'

Comment: how to refer to my table(for example: options) it sqys:

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'group'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'model'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'owner'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'group'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'model'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'owner'.

Comment: You need to add FROM [table name] before the WHERE clause. I don't know how you called your table.